# What are the options for connecting a non trivial single table dynamodb to a react front end?

Tags: reactjs, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

What are the options for connecting a non trivial single table dynamodb to a react front end? I'm using cognito user pools/auth and have got them working using amplify auth with custom components quite nicely, but my access patterns for the single table ddb just don't seem to work well with the amplify api graphql approach.

So, is there a way of calling an endpoint (eg http api gateway) with the cognito auth taken care of that doesn't use amplify?

Any help/advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've built a React app and connected it to my backend (Cognito, API Gateway, Lambda, DynamoDB, etc) via a REST API.  My DDB is a single table.  I used AWS Amplify in the front-end and it's been working well.

Here's a snippet of what a call to my back-end looks like using AWS Amplify

```
import {API, Auth} from "aws-amplify";


export default function MyComponent() {

  // variables, hooks, etc. go here

  async function handleSubmit(widget) {
    let widget = await createWidget(widget);
    // do stuff with widget
  } 

  async function createWidget(widget) {

    try {
      const args = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${(await Auth.currentSession())
            .getIdToken()
            .getJwtToken()}`
        },
        body: {
          // data to send to my API goes here
        }
      };
    
      return API.post("my_api", "/widgets", args);
    } catch (e) {
      // do error handling
    }
  }

  return (
    // form with onSubmit=handleSubmit(widget)
  );
}
```

In this snippet, I'm using Aplify's Auth and API classes to make calls to my back-end.  My application uses JWT tokens to make authenticated calls to my API, so I use Amplify's `Auth` class to get the tokens I need to send along with my request (in the header).  I'm not using graphql, but I suspect the process is similar.

If you *don't* want to use Amplify, I don't see why you couldn't just query the API directly with a client of your choice.

You say that your access patterns don't seem to work well with Amplify.  Can you elaborate on why that is?

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer, I think that's what I'm looking for. I'm still new to amplify and tbh pretty new to graphql too. At the moment I'm not sure whether a single ddb table should have many @models. Still got plenty to read...